# How to read manga in non-aligned format?

Tags: naruto

I commonly see the following layout below in Naruto.

```
+-------------+-----+
|             |     |
|             |     |
|             |     |
+-------------+     |
|             |     |
|             +-----+
|             |     |
+-------------+     |
|             |     |
|             |     |
|             |     |
+-------------+-----+
```

I'm aware that manga is [commonly read from right to left](http://www.wikihow.com/Read-Manga). As of now, I assume the following flow:

```
+-------------+-----+
|             |     |
|     2       |  1  |
|             |     |
+-------------+     |
|             |     |
|     3       +-----+
|             |     |
+-------------+     |
|             |  4  |
|     5       |     |
|             |     |
+-------------+-----+
```

Is this the right way to read this layout?

Comment: See: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4573/how-do-i-read-manga-with-multiple-panes/4578#4578. The accepted answer should answer your question.

Comment: When reading manga, when the right side panels don't align perfectly with the left i would continue to read down so given this case i would read panel 4 before going to 2, it makes sense to me as 1 leads into 4 rather than 1 leading into 2 and 3 at the same time (since the bottom of 1 is half way down 3)

Comment: @Memor-X makes sense. Anyway, I just default to your suggestion and try another order, just as kuwaly suggested if your suggestion doesn't make sense. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an example of one of such pages? It's easier to figure out the flow once you understand the context.

Comment: The manga is Naruto, there is no manga called Naruto Shippuden.

Comment: @Happy I see, if I'm not mistaken, *Naruto Shippuden* is the anime adoption of the part 2 of the manga Naruto. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Yeah, the 85 consecutive filler episodes before the time skip caused the TV show ratings to drop so low, that they realised that a change in name was needed to get people back on to the show. If they had continued the series with the same name, most people would think it is the same garbage going on. :)

Comment: @Krazer I'm speaking in general, though I'll provide two examples to see how you'll read these. [Neji death](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-fY6WKzpWk78/UOQCeTsdKCI/AAAAAAAABSg/xbbNCL1SXBQ/s1600/03.jpg) and Naruto 647: Regrets, page 18